# Dynamic scheduling with properties in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, scheduling

I am using `Spring Boot` and have an issue related `@Scheduled`.

```
@Scheduled(fixedRateString = "${timeRate}")
public void SaveStatisticData() {

    System.out.println("save Info per "+timeRate+"msec");
    ...
}
```

this is a part of my code. this method will run by `timeRate` value from properties and Properties File is connected with web API.
That means someone can request to change `timeRate` in Properties File.

I want to know how to reload `spring boot` on client request which change Properties File.

AFAIK, I can use `Hot Swapping` in spring boot.
But I think this solution is not good to service.
Because The service have to reload whenever a client request changing `timeRate`.

In other words, is there another way to apply this client request in real time?

Comment: Hi, have you asked the similar question yesterday? I found it: [How to inject '@Scheduled value' in spring boot from CouchDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47300671/how-to-inject-scheduled-value-in-spring-boot-from-couchdb).

Comment: Yes, I've made a little progress from yesterday. And now my issue is just one thing that how I can reload spring boot automatically.